# как распаковать списки в списке и добавить все в список?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список:

```
mylist = [[13, 12], [16, 19], [100, 12]]
```

что мне нужно с ним сделать, чтобы получить:

```
sorted_list = [13, 12, 16, 19, 100, 12]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, списковое сокращение с двумя циклами `for`:

```py
sorted_list = [x for y in mylist for x in y]
```

Хотя вы могли и обычными циклами это сделать с `.append` в список.

Или один цикл и `.extend` в список.